# pyQt5 pass a file object to QWebEngineView

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

how to send an opened file inside the main application to a page in QWebEngineView and handle it by javascript FileReader() function , as it was opened by an html5 file input inside the QWebEngineView

here is a part of my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys,  os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import ( QApplication,  QMainWindow)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets as QtWebEngineWidgets
import interface

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = interface.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        web_view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.web_view = web_view
        self.ui.verticalLayout_navigateur.addWidget(web_view)
        url = self.local_url("src/index.html")
        self.web_view.load(url)

        f = open('myfile.json', 'r') 
        #send f to self.web_view and handle it by javascript FileReader() function
    def local_url(self, relativePath):
        absolutePath = os.path.abspath(relativePath)
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(absolutePath)
        return url
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: i didn't find how to do it, or even if it's possible to do it, any help would be worth , and i am not asking for full code , just guides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found an alternative solution, it's quite simple, instead of sending object file to read with javascript, i have just to read it in the main application and inject the content via a QWebChannel